# Mocking Express Request with Jest and Typescript using correct types

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs

I have been having some trouble getting the correct Express Request type working in Jest. I have a simple user registration passing with this code:

```
import { userRegister } from '../../controllers/user';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

describe('User Registration', () => {
  test('User has an invalid first name', async () => {
    const mockRequest: any = {
      body: {
        firstName: 'J',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        email: 'jdoe@abc123.com',
        password: 'Abcd1234',
        passwordConfirm: 'Abcd1234',
        company: 'ABC Inc.',
      },
    };

    const mockResponse: any = {
      json: jest.fn(),
      status: jest.fn(),
    };

    const mockNext: NextFunction = jest.fn();

    await userRegister(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext);

    expect(mockNext).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockNext).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      new Error('First name must be between 2 and 50 characters')
    );
  });
});
```

However, if I change:

```
    const mockRequest: any = {
      body: {
        firstName: 'J',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        email: 'jdoe@abc123.com',
        password: 'Abcd1234',
        passwordConfirm: 'Abcd1234',
        company: 'ABC Inc.',
      },
    };
```

to:

```
const mockRequest: Partial<Request> = {
  body: {
    firstName: 'J',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'jdoe@abc123.com',
    password: 'Abcd1234',
    passwordConfirm: 'Abcd1234',
    company: 'ABC Inc.',
  },
};
```

From the TypeScript documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt), this should make all fields on the Request object optional.

However, I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'Partial<Request>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Request'.
  Property '[Symbol.asyncIterator]' is missing in type 'Partial<Request>' but required in type 'Request'.ts(2345)
stream.d.ts(101, 13): '[Symbol.asyncIterator]' is declared here.
```

I was hoping that someone with a little more TypeScript experience could comment and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You're right about what `Partial<Request>` is doing, but I'm betting that the trouble is that `userRegister` does not accept `Partial<Request>` - it requires `Request` right? Are you able to declare mockRequest as `Request` ? `const mockRequest: Partial<Request> ...` If not, you could us an assertion:     `await userRegister(mockRequest as Request, mockResponse, mockNext);`

Comment: Right now it looks like this: `export const userRegister = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
) => {`. The mock is inside a test. I got around it for now by using: `const mockRequest: any = {
      body: {
        firstName: 'J',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        email: 'jdoe@abc123.com',
        password: 'Abcd1234',
        passwordConfirm: 'Abcd1234',
        company: 'ABC Inc.',
      },
    };`. But I was told to try not to use `any` whenever possible as it defeats the purpose of TypeScript.

Comment: Ahhhh. I see. Yes, `userRegister` does require `req: express.Request` and `res: express.Response`. Interesting, but for testing, is there a way to get around that? I guess I became confused when `any` worked.

Comment: Can you post the userRegister function here so we can see the type declaration of this function?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Your mock data type doesn't have to perfectly fit the actual data.
Well, it doesn't by definition. It's just a mock, right?

What you need is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). It's a way to tell TypeScript *"Okay bro, I know what I'm doing here."*.

This is not a production code, it's a test. You're probably even running it in watch mode. We can reject some type safety here without problem. TypeScript doesn't know it's a mock, but we do.

```
const mockRequest = {
    body: {
    firstName: 'J',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'jdoe@abc123.com',
    password: 'Abcd1234',
    passwordConfirm: 'Abcd1234',
    company: 'ABC Inc.',
    },
} as Request;
```

If something crashes during the test, because `mockRequest` isn't similar to Request enough, we'll know and we'll fix the mock, add some new properties etc.

If `as Request` doesn't work you can tell TypeScript *"I REALLY know what I'm doing here"* by asserting to `any` or `unknown` first and then to the type you need. It would look like

```
const x: number = "not a number :wink:" as any as number;
```

It's useful when we'd like to test that our code doesn't work well with bad input.

For your particular case -- mocking express Request -- there is [jest-express](https://github.com/jameswlane/jest-express) to help you, if you can spare the node_modules size of course.

Comment: Now when I call the `userRegister` function though, I get this TS error `Argument of type 'Request' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/nrb/Development/partsync-server/node_modules/@types/express/index").Request'.
  Type 'Request' is missing the following properties from type 'Request': get, header, accepts, acceptsCharsets, and 68 more.ts(2345)`

Comment: Hey NickB. you have two Requests. One is global and typed in @types/node, the other one is from Express.

This is mildly annoying.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcgAIwJ5gKYGcD0A7CAEwwQG4BYAKFEljgCo4BDLODADzCm1YDMoIIRBy48yVKsQDGAGybc4UiHizwoAOSIYAXHABKGAI4BXbDAqVJGWfIyLlquFACinbliy6R7rADoDJmYWQA

Comment: If it still breaks, you can simply replace `as Request` with `as any as Request` or simply `as any`.

Thank you so much. Great answer.

Answer (score 7):

For future search about this theme, I recommend seeing this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mocks-http

This library has methods to create mocked objects for Request and Response of the Express Framework, which helped me a lot and was the easy way I found.

Simple unit test example:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import {
  createRequest, createResponse, MockRequest, MockResponse,
} from 'node-mocks-http';
import { AppController } from './app-controller';
import { APP_NAME, APP_VERSION } from '../../constants';

describe('AppController - UnitTestCase', () => {
  let controller: AppController;
  let request: MockRequest<Request>;
  let response: MockResponse<Response>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    controller = new AppController();
    /** Response Mock */
    response = createResponse();
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('GET /', () => {
    it('should return 200 and API Name + API Version', (done) => {
      /** Request Mock */
      request = createRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/',
      });

      AppController.index(request, response);

      const body = { app: `${APP_NAME}:${APP_VERSION}` };
      const result = response._getJSONData();
      expect(result).toMatchObject(body);
      expect(result.app).toEqual(body.app);
      expect(response.getHeaders()).toHaveProperty('content-type');
      console.log('headers', response.getHeaders());
      console.log('response body', result);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `userRegister` is the problem as @kschaer said. If you want that function to take in a `Partial<Request>` you can change `userRegister` to:

```js
const userRegister = async (req: Partial<Request>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => { /* snippet */ }
```

But since this is just for tests you could also cast `mockRequest` to the `Request` type like this:

```js
const mockRequest = <Request>{
  body: {
    /* snippet */
  }
};
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: When I do that, I now get this TS error: `Type '{ body: { firstName: string; lastName: string; email: string; password: string; passwordConfirm: string; company: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '<Request>() => any'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'body' does not exist in type '<Request>() => any'.`

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

*(This is the short version of [Anderson Contreira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72674717/10795361) answer).*

Use **`node-mocks-http`**. It can create `expressjs`-compatible requests and responses with necessary methods and fields.

How to use:

```
import { createRequest, createResponse } from 'node-mocks-http';

const req = createRequest();
const res = createResponse();
```

Modify the request:

```
req.headers['x-my-header'] = 'test';
```

Tested with `jest` and `NestJs`.

You may find `express.request` and `express.response` prototypes, but they do **NOT** help to create proper objects with all methods, at least in the TypeScript environment.